# javascript firstChild property shows double low 9 "„" after setting string as innerHTML on element

Tags: javascript, dom

check my below code, inside while loop, node value shows double low 9 "„" character at the end.

```
let html = '{{c1::some text}}'
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html 
    
while (node = div.firstChild) {
   console.log(node); // "some text„"
   lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `html`?

Comment: @Sgnl ```html = '{{c1::some text}}'```

Comment: That doesn't look like html, could be the reason why it's erroring? Looks like templating code. What does `c1::some text` resolve too?

Comment: ```c1::some text``` is just a string, I'm not using any templating engine or any framework. It's just pure javascript. When I try to test the above code outside the chrome extension, it works well, but inside the function it creates this problem

Comment: Yes, "innerHTML" want's an HTML string. so try replacing it with HTML like `<div class="parent-div"><p>test text</p></div>` and see what happens?

Comment: this value is not in my control, and it is not always plain text, sometimes it contains html markup also

Comment: Have you checked to see if your text contains hidden characters?